# Math.random() in Javascipt giving quite non-random looking distribution

Tags: javascript, random

I'm running a study which redirects participants to one of 8 random websites using the below piece of javascript (on an otherwise blank HTML page).

What's odd is the distribution of participants to each site. I have about 64 participants so far and I know that true randomness does not mean there should be 8 visitors to each site. However, one of the sites only has had a single redirect (site number 5) while another one has had 19 (site number 1). The others are all close to 8 visits each.

I just wanted to check that I haven't made any silly mistakes/assumptions with such a simple code. I can't think of any reason why it would be much more likely to generate a "1" and much less likely to generate a "5".

Is it just the case that this is the luck of the draw with random number generation and that one can end up with some sites being visited 19 more times that others while sample size is low and there are 8 possibilities?

Any opinions would be really appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function randomlinks(){
        var myrandom=Math.floor(Math.random()*8)
        var links=new Array()
        links[0]="[website0 name here]"
        links[1]="[website1]"
        links[2]="[website2]"
        links[3]="[website3]"
        links[4]="[website4]"
        links[5]="[website5]"
        links[6]="[website6]"
        links[7]="[website7]"
     
        window.location=links[myrandom]
        }
    
    randomlinks();
</script>
```

Comment: [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) is pseudo-random

Comment: Consider using an array literal instead? `var links = ["[website0]","[website1]","[website2]", ...]`?

Comment: AFAIK there is no "true randomness" in any programming language. It's why people use external sources for true randomness https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/lava-lamp-encryption/

Comment: You haven't made a "silly mistake". Random numbers are just ... well, random.

Comment: For your use case it’s fine. `Math.random` is uniformly distributed. What you observed was pure luck.

Comment: For more technical details ref [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/84906/predicting-math-random-numbers)

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback all. Based on the above comments, it seems it's due to chance and not to something systematic. And thanks for the additional reading everybody!

Comment: @evolutionxbox [crypto.randomBytes](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) and [SystemRandom](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom) exist.  on most mainstream OSs these will give the caller "true" randomness (i.e. providing reasonable bounds on forward and backward secrecy, even if the complete state of the system is known)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems the slightly odd looking redirection numbers are due to chance alone and not to something systematic in the code. Thanks again all!